# Dynamically accessing a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dynamic, accessor

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'one' : [1,2,3],
                   'two' : [1,0,0]})

df 
Out[9]: 
   one  two
0    1    1
1    2    0
2    3    0
```

I want to write a function that takes as inputs a dataframe `df` and a column `mycol`.

Now this works:

```
df.groupby('one').two.sum()
Out[10]: 
one
1    1
2    0
3    0
Name: two, dtype: int64
```

this works too:

```
 def okidoki(df,mycol):
    return df.groupby('one')[mycol].sum()

okidoki(df, 'two')
Out[11]: 
one
1    1
2    0
3    0
Name: two, dtype: int64
```

but this **FAILS**

```
def megabug(df,mycol):
    return df.groupby('one').mycol.sum()

megabug(df, 'two')
 AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mycol'
```

What is wrong here?

I am worried that `okidoki` uses some *chaining* that might create some subtle bugs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

How can I still keep the syntax `groupby('one').mycol`? Can the `mycol` string be converted to something that might work that way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass a string as the second argument. In effect, you're trying to do something like:

```
df.'two'
```

Which is invalid syntax. If you're trying to dynamically access a column, you'll need to use the index notation, `[...]` because the dot/attribute accessor notation doesn't work for dynamic access.

---

Dynamic access on its own is possible. For example, you can use `getattr` (but I *don't* recommend this, it's an antipattern):

```
In [674]: df
Out[674]: 
   one  two
0    1    1
1    2    0
2    3    0

In [675]: getattr(df, 'one')
Out[675]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: one, dtype: int64
```

Dynamically selecting by attribute from a groupby call can be done, something like:

```
In [677]: getattr(df.groupby('one'), mycol).sum() 
Out[677]: 
one
1    1
2    0
3    0
Name: two, dtype: int64
```

But *don't* do it. It is a horrid anti pattern, and much more unreadable than `df.groupby('one')[mycol].sum()`.

Comment: thanks coldspeed. I have edited my question. My point is, given a string as an input, is it possible to kind of convert it to something that will work with this syntax? say `notastring = magicfunction(mycol)` and then `df.notastring`

Comment: @ℕℴℴḆḽḘ Edited my answer again. It is possible but it is a horrid anti pattern. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `[]` for select column by column name what is general solution for selecting columns, because select by attributes have many [exceptions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access):

> - You can use this access only if the index element is a valid python identifier, e.g. s.1 is not allowed. See here for an explanation of valid identifiers.
> - The attribute will not be available if it conflicts with an existing method name, e.g. s.min is not allowed.
> - Similarly, the attribute will not be available if it conflicts with any of the following list: index, major_axis, minor_axis, items, labels.
> - In any of these cases, standard indexing will still work, e.g. s['1'], s['min'], and s['index'] will access the corresponding element or column.

```
def megabug(df,mycol):
    return df.groupby('one')[mycol].sum()

print (megabug(df, 'two'))

one
1    1
2    0
3    0
Name: two, dtype: int64
```

Comment: yes jezrael, this is the okidoki function above actually :D. My question is why it is the case?